# What is the difference between testbed.get and inject in Angular 2/Jasmine testing?

Tags: angular, jasmine, testbed

I am new to Angular 2 testing. I am trying to figure out what is the difference in using `testsbed.get()` and just using `inject` at the test level.

eg:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [SomeService]
    });

    const testbed = getTestBed();
    someService= testbed.get(SomeService);
  });
});
```

vs

```
it('test service', inject([SomeService], (someService: SomeService) => {
```

Comment: I added Jasmine to tags and title for you. As it's the key technology this question relates to.

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but digging the code: `inject` calls `testbed.get` internally. The main difference is that if you provide `AsyncTestCompleter` to `inject` it will run `compileComponents` and the object provided has a `done` function that completes the execution of an async test. Looks like this is old code and it is preferred to use `async(inject(` instead. Then from this point looks like a syntax preference matter.

Comment: v4 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts#L493
/ v2 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.x/modules/%40angular/core/testing/test_bed.ts#L404

Comment: @BrunoLM AsyncTestCompleter has been used internally. It isn't a concern for end user, making inject efficiently the same thing as testBed.get

Answer (score 44):

Just to add to the existing answer and if like me you found this question because you are wondering what the difference is between `TestBed.get()` and `TestBed.inject()` which I know was not quite what the OP originally asked but it is relevant and is very much related.

I thought it was worth posting that according to the latest Angular documentation that `TestBed.inject()` is the type safe replacement of `TestBed.get()`.

From the Angular documentation on `TestBed` that can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#angular-testbed).

[image]

Comment: `TestBed.inject` was introduced in Angular v9, at the same time `TestBed.get` was deprecated.

Answer (score 29):

`inject` helper function was historically used since AngularJS as an alternative to direct injector calls. In Angular 1, it was necessary to bootstrap a test with `ngMock`. It is entirely optional in Angular 2 and higher and is just a suggested way for DI in TestBed tests.

[It a convenience wrapper for `testBed.get`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.1/packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts#L508) that allows to avoid multiple `testBed.get` calls, similarly to:

```
const [foo, bar] = [Foo, Bar].map(TestBed.get);
```

Other helper functions can be optionally used in conjunction with `inject`, namely `async` and `fakeAsync`.

Answer (score 2):

**These used to be equivalent, but with Angular 9 the preferred method became *inject()*.**

`TestBed.get()` is deprecated in Angular 9+, and `TestBed.inject()` is now the preferred type-safe way to inject a dependency.

Read the documentation for clarity: [TestBed.get()](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed#inject) and [TestBed.inject()](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed#inject). The change is one of deprecation.