# I can't get FormBuilder from TestBed with FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule imported

Tags: forms, angular, testing, dependency-injection

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
    ]
});

TestBed.get(FormBuilder);
```

What do I need to do? Or I should just use new operator to create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [you can](http://plnkr.co/edit/WuA43kahGlPhUhT0Fdiw?p=preview):

```
describe('FormBuilder', () => {
  let fb;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ]
    });

    fb = TestBed.get(FormBuilder);
  });

  it('should be FormBuilder instance', () => {
    expect(fb instanceof FormBuilder).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43079664/what-is-the-difference-between-testbed-get-and-inject-in-angular-2-jasmine-testi), `TestBed.get` is same thing as `inject` helper, it creates an injector on first call and gets provider instance.

`FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` are mutually exclusive and aren't supposed to be used together, but this shouldn't affect the result.