# Angular 5 testing code in module constructor

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test code that's in one of my module's constructor. Basically, the module (named `GraphqlModule`) configures a service (named `Graphql`) and provides it. The configuration happens in the module's constructor.

Here's the code I use to test the module.

```
it('should use the GraphqlConfigs and ServerConfigs', (done: DoneFn) => {

    // Adding spies to Config classes
    let serverConfigs = new ServerConfigs();
    let serverDomainSpy = spyOnProperty(serverConfigs, 'ServerDomain', 'get').and.callThrough();
    let serverPortSpy = spyOnProperty(serverConfigs, 'ServerPort', 'get').and.callThrough();

    let gqlConfigs = new GraphqlConfigs();
    let protocolSpy = spyOnProperty(gqlConfigs, 'EndpointProtocol', 'get').and.callThrough();
    let endpointNameSpy = spyOnProperty(gqlConfigs, 'EndpointName', 'get').and.callThrough();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ GraphqlModule ],
        providers: [
            {provide: ServerConfigs, useValue: serverConfigs}, // Replacing real config classes with the ones spied on.
            {provide: GraphqlConfigs, useValue: gqlConfigs}
        ]

    }).compileComponents().then(() => {

        // This line seems to make Angular instantiate GraphqlModule
        const graphql = TestBed.get(Graphql) as Graphql;

        expect(serverDomainSpy.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'ServerConfigs.ServerDomain was not used.');
        expect(serverPortSpy.calls.count()).toBe(1,  'ServerConfigs.ServerPort was not used.');

        expect(protocolSpy.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'GraphqlConfigs.EndpointProtocol was not used.');
        expect(endpointNameSpy.calls.count()).toBe(1,  'GraphqlConfigs.EndpointName was not used.');

        done();
    });
});
```

As is, the test passes and works, but if I dont use the following (useless) line `const graphql = TestBed.get(Graphql) as Graphql;` the `GraphqlModule` gets instantiated after the test has been executed, which makes the test fail.

Since it's `GraphqlModule` that provides the `Graphql` service, I understand that there's some lazy loading algorithm in Angular that's triggered when I do `TestBed.get(Graphql)`. That's fine... my question is, is there a way to make my module load in a more **explicit** way?

Here's the GraphqlModule class definition:

```
imports...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ApolloModule,
        HttpLinkModule
    ],
    declarations: [],

    providers: [
        Graphql, // Is an alias for Apollo
        GraphqlConfigs
    ]
})
export class GraphqlModule {

    constructor(
        @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: GraphqlModule,
        graphql: Graphql,
        httpLink: HttpLink,
        serverConfigs: ServerConfigs,
        graphqlConfigs: GraphqlConfigs
    ) {

        // Making sure this is not imported twice.
        // https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#prevent-reimport-of-the-coremodule
        if (parentModule) {
            throw new Error(
                'GraphqlModule is already loaded. Import it in the '+CoreModule.name+' only.');
        }

        // Gql setup:


        const gqlHttpLink = httpLink.create({
            uri: GraphqlModule.buildEndpointUrl(serverConfigs, graphqlConfigs)
        });

        graphql.create({
            link: gqlHttpLink,
            cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        });
    }

    private static buildEndpointUrl(serverConfigs: ServerConfigs, graphqlConfigs: GraphqlConfigs): string {

        return graphqlConfigs.EndpointProtocol +                            // eg. http://
            serverConfigs.ServerDomain+":"+serverConfigs.ServerPort+'/' +   // eg. example.com:80/
            graphqlConfigs.EndpointName;                                    // eg. graphql
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're testing, because the question doesn't contain GraphqlModule or Graphql. *I'm trying to test code that's in one of my module's constructor* - it isn't listed.

Comment: @estus The module is listed in the `Testbed`'s import configuration. This test is part of a test suite that test different features of the `GraphqlModule`

Comment: Sorry, I put it in the question's body, however, I'm not sure it's relevant to my question though.

Comment: It was necessary to understand what's going on, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Graphql` is already instantiated in `GraphqlModule` constructor for root injector, and `GraphqlModule` is eagerly instantiated when it's specified in TestBed `imports`. There's no lazy loading involved.

As it's explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47335613/3731501), TestBed injector is instantiated on first `inject` callback call, or `TestBed.get`, or `TestBed.createComponent` call. The injector doesn't exist until the first injection, so don't any module or provider instances. Since almost all TestBed tests perform at least one of these calls in `it` or `beforeEach`, this issue usually never appears.

Since `graphql` instance isn't needed in this test, in order for the test to pass it can be just:

```
TestBed.get(Injector);
```

Or:

```
TestBed.get(TestBed);
```

Also, `.compileComponents().then(() => { ... })` and `done()` are unnecessary, the test doesn't involve components and is synchronous.

The fact that the injector needs to be instantiated manually suggests that TestBed isn't required for this test, although it's beneficial because this way `GraphqlModule` constructor DI annotation can be tested, including the one for `parentModule`.

Comment: Wow, epic answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Estus my test is failing due to  (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: GraphqlModule) getting error Property name expected type of string but got null i am using ngMock. when i remove parentModule property from module constructor it work fine