# Angular 11 - Test case writing - Jasmine - deprecation issue

Tags: angular, unit-testing, types, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to create my very first test case using Jasmine and its my first attempt in writing test cases(actually just started learning). I'm currently referring [This site](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/angularjs/unit-testing-angular-services) to write test case

Here I'm facing two issues.

1. The signature '(token: any, notFoundValue?: any): any' of 'TestBed.get' is deprecated.ts(6387)
   testing.d.ts(382, 9): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.
   (method) TestBedStatic.get(token: any, notFoundValue?: any): any (+1 overload)
2. Argument of type '(typeof EmployeeService)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type | AbstractType | InjectionToken'.
   Type '(typeof EmployeeService)[]' is missing the following properties from type 'AbstractType': prototype, apply, call, bind, and 4 more.ts(2345)

**employee model**

```
export interface Employee {
    name: string;
    desc: null | string;
    action: string;
    obj: Obj;
    action: any;

}

export interface Obj {
    empId: string;
    empName: string;
    reportTo: string;
    country: string;
    region: string;
    empStatus: string;
    department: string;
}
```

**testcase**

```
describe('DataAccessService', () => {
    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
    let dataAccessService: EmployeeService;
    // let baseUrl = 'czm/getCustomerList';
    let traveller: Employee;
  
    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
      });
  
      httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
      traveller = {
        name: 'Jane',
        desc: 'Jane',
        action: '',
        obj: {
          empId: 'Jane',
          empName: 'Jane',
          reportTo: 'TD1',
          country: 'USA',
          region: 'USA',
          empStatus: 'Inactive',
          department: 'HR - Marketing',
        }
      };
    });
  
    beforeEach(inject(
      [EmployeeService],
      (service: EmployeeService) => {
        dataAccessService = service;
      }
    ));
  });
```

Could someone tell me how to resolve this issue?

I'm requesting some **jasmine experts** to create stackblitz if possible

Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

`TestBed.get` is deprecated, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60339076). Just use `TestBed.inject` instead of `TestBed.get` since Angular 9.